# Why does .NET Core 2.2 API with SharePointOnline CSOM throw "The process has no package identity"?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 API running on IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter machine. It uses the DLLs from Nuget package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM. But it throws exception `One or more errors occurred. (The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54))` when calling method `ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync()`.

I have followed the following guide: https://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/ . I have tried two solutions. The first was creating a .NET Core Console solution that calls the DLL containing the SharePoint CSOM code. Then I tried calling the DLL from a .NET Core 2.2 API running on IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter machine. But both solutions throw the same exception as mentioned above `One or more errors occurred. (The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54))`.

The SharePointHelper.dll code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SharePointHelper
{
  public class SharePointHelper
  {

    public SharePointHelper() { }

    public void WriteFilesAndFolders(string siteUrl, string listName, string username, string password)
    {
      using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
      {
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

        var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(listName);
        var subFolders = folder.Folders;
        var files = folder.Files;

        context.Load(folder);
        context.Load(subFolders);
        context.Load(files);

        if (context.HasPendingRequest)
          context.ExecuteQueryAsync().Wait();

        var subFolderEnumorator = subFolders.GetEnumerator();
        var filesEnumerator = files.GetEnumerator();
        PrintValues(subFolderEnumorator);
        PrintValues(filesEnumerator);
      }
    }

    private void PrintValues(IEnumerator<Folder> enumerator)
    {
      while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Name);
    }

    private void PrintValues(IEnumerator<File> enumerator)
    {
      while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Name);
    }

  }

}
```

The .NET Core 2.2 service code calling the method in the SharePointHelper.dll:

```
public void SharePointTest()
    {
      string siteUrl = @"https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Test";
      string listName = "Documents";
      string username = "myemail@somecompany.com";
      string password = "mypassword";

      var sharePointHelper = new SharePointHelper.SharePointHelper();
      sharePointHelper.WriteFilesAndFolders(siteUrl, listName, username, password);
    }
```

I expect the SharePointHelper.dll to connect and get a response from SharePoint. But exception `One or more errors occurred. (The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54))` is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem to use SharePoint with .NET Core by simply installing the `TTCUE.NetCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM` Nuget package. No reason to follow the linked guide unless you want to understand how to do the workaround in depth.